# Why ContentVC's viewWill/DidAppear is called before its parent(PageVC)?

Tags: ios, uipageviewcontroller, lifecycle

In my case, I use ViewController as parent of PageViewController. And it also be the dataSource of PageViewController by providing ContentViewController.

It's strange that ContentViewController's `-viewWill/DidAppear:` is called before it's parent, here is what I got from console:

```
[ContentViewController viewWillAppear:]
[ContentViewController viewDidAppear:]
[ViewController viewWillAppear:]
[PageViewController viewWillAppear:]
[ViewController viewDidAppear:]
[PageViewController viewDidAppear:]
```

Here are some code from ViewController.m:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    PageViewController *pageVC = [[PageViewController alloc] initWithTransitionStyle:UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll navigationOrientation:UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationHorizontal options:nil];;
    pageVC.dataSource = self;
    [pageVC setViewControllers:@[[self contentViewControllerWithIndex:0]]
                      direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward
                       animated:NO completion:nil];
    pageVC.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    pageVC.view.frame = self.view.bounds;
    [self addChildViewController:pageVC];
    [self.view addSubview:pageVC.view];
    [pageVC didMoveToParentViewController:self];
}


-(ContentViewController  *)contentViewControllerWithIndex:(NSInteger )index {
    ContentViewController *vc = [[ContentViewController alloc] init];
    vc.index = index;
    return vc;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: From where `contentViewControllerWithIndex ` function get called, there is your answer..

Answer (score 0):

If you go through line by line of your code

- This line just alloc your `PageViewController`. It has actually not added it on top of your `ViewController`. So `ViewWillAppear` for `PageViewController` will not get called here.

Code:

```
PageViewController *pageVC = [[PageViewController alloc] initWithTransitionStyle:UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll navigationOrientation:UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationHorizontal options:nil];
```

- Below line is calling `[self contentViewControllerWithIndex:0]` which will be allocating the `ContentViewController` also adding it on `PageVC` so `ViewWillAppear` for `ContentViewController` is called

Code:

```
[pageVC setViewControllers:@[[self contentViewControllerWithIndex:0]]
                      direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward
                       animated:NO completion:nil];
```

- Below line is adding `PageVC` as `childViewController`of `ViewController`. So once the `ViewWillAppear` of `ViewController` will be called then only it can call `ViewWillAppear` of `PageVC` and add it as its childView.

Code:

```
[self addChildViewController:pageVC];
[self.view addSubview:pageVC.view];
[pageVC didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

Comment: As you said,  "adding it on`PageVC` so `ViewWillAppear` for ContentViewController is called".  But why `viewWillAppear` of `PageVC` still not called when adding pageVC.view to self.view? Do they(child-parent pair for ContentVC-PageVC, PageVC-VC) share same behavior?

Comment: The page view controller has no UI of its own; however, it does add a page curl effect to its children while the user is turning the page. The custom content is provided by the view controllers that are children of the page view controller. For more information https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/PageViewControllers.html